# OpenCL usage of register value crashes program

Tags: opencl, gpu

I finished writing an OpenCL kernel for thermodynamics calculations and observed a really weird bug. 
My kernel looks like this:

```
__kernel void energy(... float3 dest, int nlocal, ...){
   int i = get_global_id(0);
   float3 ev = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
   for(...){
      //some thermo calculations, adding values to evx and evy
       ev.x +=...;
       ev.y +=...;
    }

    //Then I want to save the result in dest[i].
    //Program exits at next two line
    dest[i].x = ev.x;
    dest[i].y = ev.y;
```

I get an "unmapped Memory" and segfault error. I get the same error when trying to print out the value using printf. Seems like the program can't read the value. Writing to it works though!(Maybe because of some compiler optimizations)
Now if I use another float register value, I get the same error. But if I change the last lines to something like this (no use of ev.x or ev.y)

```
dest[i].x = i/nlocal*3.1f
dest[i].y = ...;
```

everything is going as expected and I get no error.

This works too:

```
int i = ...
float3 = {0.0f, ...}
dest[i].x = ev.x;
```

But somehow after the actual calculation it is not possible anymore.

The program is running on a Nvidia K40m, Kepler architecture.

Comment: The problem can also be here: `ev.x +=...; ev.y +=...;`. CL compiler will simply delete code that does not affect to the output array. Post a reproducible code example otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have changed my code. It is the whole kernel now.

Answer (score 1):

This looks suspicious in your code:

```
kernel(... __global int* neigh
   __global int* neighs = neigh+i;
   ...
   int j = neighs[k*n];
   ...
```

Seems like you are passing a array of pointers in `neigh`, then getting the pointer and using it.
Pointers are not allowed in CL, if you pass pointers then you are addressing out of the GPU memory, and therefore crashing.

It is also possible that your vectors are simply not properly calculated, the sizes should be:

```
res, nneigh = GLOBAL_SIZE
neighs = max(nneigh[])*n
x = max(neighs[])
```

And also possible you did create the buffers smaller than they should be (remember they are floats, and float3, which use 32bits and 128bits per element). CL API calls are defined in bytes (you should use `sizeof()`), not in elements.

Comment: I think I found the problem that caused the segfault. I passed sizeof(numneigh) twice and not the sizeof(neigh). Now I get a OutOfResources Error when I use ev.x or ev.y ... When I write other values to res everything goes as expected.

Comment: _Seems like you are passing a array of pointers in neigh, then getting the pointer and using it._ - to me this looks more like accessing 2D flattened array. @Noahnder it would be worth to include host code too, as already mentioned there must be something wrong with the sizes of the OpenCL buffers. If you write other values to res then the rest of the code gets optimized out so you are basically not using it and the problem disappears.

Comment: @doqtor I would see more logical to use `neighs[k*n+i]` rather than getting a pointer to a element i, and then offseting it again in the major dimension. Seems unnatural. Thats why I guessed that maybe he has an array of pointers in `neighs`, and he was doing that just to make it compile.
I agree that Host code is needed to debug these kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the answer and the code above is working. I changed the kernel parameters for better understanding and corrected the mistake unconsiously when I posted the code here.

```
int numneigh = nneigh[i] (stands for number of neighbors) is correct
in the original code I did this: 
int numneigh = neigh[i] (the neighbors)
```

Thanks for helping, and your guess that something is wrong with neigh/nneigh was correct, even though the mistake was not in code posted above :P